# Vanishing xampp-control.exe

Tags: windows-8

I'm running XAMPP on windows 8 home edition. the program installed easily and ran perfectly for about 8 weeks there was a shortcut on the START panel and on the DESKTOP.  Today I tried to access it and got a response indicating the program did not exist.  When I looked in the XAMPP directory sure enough there was no sign of xampp-control.exe. I hagve no idea what happened to it and my question is do I have to reinstall XAMPP to get it back or can I copy it from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see the exe in the installation folder you will need to reinstall. On that note, if this is a frequent occurence back up your drive and run the manufacturers diagnostic utility / a good solid chkdsk.